# Remove the popup message after removing the sql document in SQL server

Tags: sql-server

Goal:
Don't display the popup when you remove/delete the sqldocument in SQL server.

Problem:
Before I downloaded the latest version of SQL server, it didn't show any popup about status when I removed the sql document.

When I downloaded the latest version of SQL server, it suddenly started to display the popup.

It always display when I remove/delete the sql document in SQL server.

How do I remove it?

Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71806872/ssms-shows-querying-transaction-count-on-closing-the-query-window

Comment: [dup on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73213582/remove-the-popup-message-after-removing-the-sql-document-in-sql-server)